# Move Items relative to current location in Powershell

Tags: powershell, relative-path

I need to traverse a folder (ParentLogFolder), find logs and move them from the relative folder (SUBLOG) to a subfolder (CompressedLogFolder)

```
ParentLogfolder  
---SubLog  
------CompressedLogFolder  
---SubLog  
------CompressedLogFolder
```

Folder structure, not limited to 2 SubLogfolders, can be 100+

```
$Path = "C:\ParentLogFolder"
$Pattern = "*.log"
$date = get-date
$AgeLimit = $date.AddDays(-31)
Get-ChildItem -Filter $Pattern -path $path -recurse | Where-Object 
{$_.LastWriteTime -lt $AgeLimit} | Move-Item -Path
```

I can't figure out how to get the files of the parent folder into a variable and add the subfolder as destination in the `Move-Item` part.

Anyone out there, who can help answer this?

Don't mind the `$Date` part of the code, it works, it's just there because it needs to be in the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of onliner, consider emphasis on code clarity. That is, break the process in substeps by divide and conquer approach. It's easier to check variables for incorrect values when the pipeline isn't used too much. Like so,

```
$allFiles = Get-ChildItem -Filter $Pattern -path $path -recurse
$oldFiles = $allFiles | ? { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $ageLimit }

foreach($file in $oldFiles) {
    $archiveFolder = join-path $file.DirectoryName 'someArchiveFolder'
    $destination = join-path $archiveFolder $file.Name
    move-item -whatif $file.FullName $destination
}
```

The `-whatif` switch will print what the move command would do. Remove it to actually move files.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code and tips.
I fairly new to doing "complex" powershell, and just couldn't figure out the correct formular.